# how to take a different random numbers in one row in the range 1..n with vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I want a vba code which all rows contain the values 1..n (n dependent from txt files) exactly once. Some cells have already values from the txt files.
That is what i did but it is not give to me that i want:

```
Function randomnum(n As Integer, ProbMatrix() As Integer) As Integer
Dim k As Integer, newvalue As Integer
    newvalue = Int(n * Rnd + 1)
    For i = 1 To n
        For k = 1 To n
            If ProbMatrix(i, k) = newvalue Then
                newvalue = RandInt(n)
                k = 0
            End If
        Next k
            randomnum = newvalue
    Next i
End function
```

Comment: You mean you want a shuffle of the integers between 1 and n? If so, then implement this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: What did it give you? It looks to me that if your `ProbMatrix(i,k) = newvalue` is hitting on a somewhat regular basis, you'll get a near infinite loop, since you reset `k=0` _inside_ the `For K = 1...` loop.

Comment: In program the user can choose one of the three example problem files. Every example problem files includes some values in an array n x n. On the first column is the number n in the example files. First we have to appear the given value in the correct position and after to fill the rows with random numbers in the range (1-n) such that all rows contain the values 1,...,n exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for a **single cell**, cell **A1**
Place a value in **A1** and run sub *Routine()* to produce a list of random numbers in the adjacent cells:

```
Sub Routine()
    Dim i As Long, MMX As Long
    MMX = Range("A1").Value
    ReDim ary(1 To MMX) As Variant

    For i = 1 To MMX
        ary(i) = i
    Next i

    Call Shuffle(ary)

    For i = 1 To MMX
        Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = ary(i)
    Next i

End Sub

Sub Shuffle(InOut() As Variant)
    Dim HowMany As Long, i As Long, J As Long

    Hi = UBound(InOut)
    Low = LBound(InOut)
    ReDim Helper(Low To Hi) As Double
    Randomize

    For i = Low To Hi
        Helper(i) = Rnd
    Next i


    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For i = Low To Hi - J
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + J) Then
            Temp = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + J)
            Helper(i + J) = Temp
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        For i = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + J) Then
            Temp = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + J)
            Helper(i + J) = Temp
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]